# How can I scale the transform while it's moving smooth slowly also using Lerp?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The goal in the script is that the transform is moving slowly smooth to another object and become that object child. This part is working fine! I'm trying now to make the object also shrink(scaling down) while it's moving.

I added the line number 67 :

```
this.transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(transform.localScale, new Vector3(0.001f, 0.001f, 0.001f), timer);
```

but the transform is not scaling slowly smooth while it's moving the scaling is starting after the transform has finished moving.  I want it to scale to 0.001 while it's moving.

second, after it's scaling the object vanish and I see in the editor on the scaling on x,y,z the value : 5e-05

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Manager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum TransitionState
    {
        None,
        MovingTowards,
        Transferring
    }

    public Transform player;
    public Transform carte;
    public Animation anim;
    public Transform destinationTransform;
    public float speed;
    public float distanceToStop;
    public float lerpTime;
    public UnlockCrate unlockCarte;

    private GameObject rig_f_middle;

    private Transform originTransform;
    private float timer;
    private bool openonce = false;

    private TransitionState state = TransitionState.MovingTowards;

    void Start()
    {
        rig_f_middle = GameObject.Find("rig_f_middle.02.R");
    }

    void Update()
    {
        var dist = Vector3.Distance(carte.position, player.position);


        if(dist < 1.5f)
        {
            if (openonce == false)
            {
                anim.Play("Crate_Open");
                openonce = true;
            }

            switch (state)
            {
                case TransitionState.MovingTowards:
                    var v = rig_f_middle.transform.position - transform.position;
                    if (v.magnitude < 0.001f)
                    {
                        state = TransitionState.Transferring;
                        originTransform = rig_f_middle.transform;
                        timer = 0;
                        return;
                    }
                    Vector3 moveDir = v.normalized;
                    transform.position += moveDir * speed * Time.deltaTime;
                    break;

                case TransitionState.Transferring:
                    timer += Time.deltaTime;
                    this.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(originTransform.position, destinationTransform.position, timer);
                    this.transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(transform.localScale, new Vector3(0.001f, 0.001f, 0.001f), timer);
                    if (timer >= 1.0f)
                    {
                        this.transform.parent = destinationTransform;
                        state = TransitionState.None;
                        this.enabled = false;
                        return;
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    this.enabled = false;
                    return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just like you do with the position you would need to lerp between original scale and target scale .. not using the current `transform.localScale` ... otherwise you reach the target pretty fast I guess

Answer (score 0):

We need to create a field to store the scale before moving

```
    private Vector3 initialScale;
```

Then in update, you need to add two lines, both of which are commented.

```
    void Update()
    {
        var dist = Vector3.Distance(carte.position, player.position);

        if(dist < 1.5f)
        {
            if (openonce == false)
            {
                anim.Play("Crate_Open");
                openonce = true;
            }

            switch (state)
            {
                case TransitionState.MovingTowards:
                    var v = rig_f_middle.transform.position - transform.position;
                    if (v.magnitude < 0.001f)
                    {
                        state = TransitionState.Transferring;
                        originTransform = rig_f_middle.transform;
                        //recording the scale before moving
                        initialScale = transform.localScale; 
                        timer = 0;
                        return;
                    }
                    Vector3 moveDir = v.normalized;
                    transform.position += moveDir * speed * Time.deltaTime;
                    break;

                case TransitionState.Transferring:
                    timer += Time.deltaTime;
                    this.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(originTransform.position, destinationTransform.position, timer);
                    // lerping from the initial to target scale
                    this.transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(initialScale, new Vector3(0.001f, 0.001f, 0.001f), timer); 
                    if (timer >= 1.0f)
                    {
                        this.transform.parent = destinationTransform;
                        state = TransitionState.None;
                        this.enabled = false;
                        return;
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    this.enabled = false;
                    return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You'll want to recheck your code. `initialScale` will be created every single Update.

Comment: @SpicyCatGames I tried it after the edit. Still, the scaling is happening only when the transform has finished moving but I want the scaling to start when the transform is started moving until the transform end Transferring. The scaling should happen along all the way and now it happens only in the end.  and the other problem still exist too after the transform is scaled it's not ending at 0.001 but on the X it's 5e-05 and on the Y and Z the values are 4.999998e-05

Comment: those numbers are very close to 0.01. I think floats are just not that precise when you're dealing with such small numbers. Donno what's happening with the scale tho, try step debugging unless someone else answers. BTW does this object have another parent before you set the parent in this code?